# Помощь в вёрстке слайдера CSS

Tags: html, css

Ребят в общем проблема в чём, в незнании. Подскажите может как это сделать или киньте может ссылку на годный сайт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сверстать такой слайдер, прямоугольный, что бы эти 3-ри вещи были как один слайд, и когда перелистывал на следующий слайд там были тоже 3-ри вещи.

```css
/*White slidere*/

ul{ list-style: none;
}

.white-slider{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 190px;
}

.slides-2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.slides-2 img{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.img-1{
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 190px;
    width: 340px;
}

.third img{
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.second{
    border-left: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.img-1 img, .img-1 h2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #afafaf;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.first h2{
    position: relative;
    left: -35px;
}

.second h2, .third h2{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.second a, .third a {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    right: 85px;
}

.first a{
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    right: -214px; 
}


/*Кнопка*/
.ghost-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #3cc395;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.ghost-button:hover,
.ghost-button:active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
/*end Кнопка*/
/*End white slider*/
```

```html
   <div class="white-slider">
    <div class="flexslider-2">
  <ul class="slides-2">
    <li>
     <div class="img-1 first">
      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/11508be250acf5997b4b2cec41cfa7bf-full.png" alt="">
      <h2>branded<br>
          shoes</h2>
    <a class="ghost-button" href="http://mnogoblog.ru/">Shop</a>
      </div>
    </li>  
      
    <li>
     <div class="img-1 second">
      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/420ee55689ecc2c582f2b8c082f7bb8a-full.png" alt="">
        <h2>branded<br>
        shoes</h2>
    <a class="ghost-button" href="http://mnogoblog.ru/">Shop</a>
      </div>
    </li>  
      
    <li>
     <div class="img-1 third">
      <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/18/7a8d6fbdfb44c11013e7935245df58a0-full.png" alt="">
        <h2>branded<br>
        shoes</h2>
    <a class="ghost-button" href="http://mnogoblog.ru/">Shop</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/merge.html), параметры `items` и `merge`. Или [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), раздел "Multiply Items".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на чистом css, то схематично можно вот так. Здесь для простоты размеры заданы абсолютные, но можно в относительные перевести по тому же принципу: условно ширина слайдера - 100%, а контейнера со слайдами - 100% * количество слайдов.

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.slider-toggles {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.slider-toggles label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider-toggles label:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.slider-slides {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  
  width: 1350px;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width = 450px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: green;
}

#toggle1:checked ~ .slider-toggles > label[for="toggle1"] {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#toggle2:checked ~ .slider-toggles > label[for="toggle2"] {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#toggle3:checked ~ .slider-toggles > label[for="toggle3"] {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#toggle1:checked ~ .slider-slides {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

#toggle2:checked ~ .slider-slides {
  transform: translateX(-450px);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

#toggle3:checked ~ .slider-slides {
  transform: translateX(-900px);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <input type="radio" name="toggle" class="toggle" id="toggle1">
    <input type="radio" name="toggle" class="toggle" id="toggle2">
    <input type="radio" name="toggle" class="toggle" id="toggle3">
    
     <div class="slider-toggles">
      <label for="toggle1"></label>
      <label for="toggle2"></label>
      <label for="toggle3"></label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slider-slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="item item1">Item1</div>
        <div class="item item2">Item2</div>
        <div class="item item3">Item3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="item item1">Item1</div>
        <div class="item item2">Item2</div>
        <div class="item item3">Item3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="item item1">Item1</div>
        <div class="item item2">Item2</div>
        <div class="item item3">Item3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Только здесь, конечно, лучше слайды списками верстать, а не дивы разводить, это я поторопилась :)